# error in installing r terra package on databricks

Tags: r, databricks, terra

I am trying to install an R package `terra` on databricks. But I get following error. I am not able to understand the error and how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Check the log file referred from the last line with `%sh cat ...log-file-name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that required libraries are missing. The project's [README says](https://github.com/rspatial/terra#linux) that you need to install following libraries: `libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev`.  You can achieve this with following [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) attached to your cluster (not tested):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```